# Resize css in mPDF

Tags: php, html, css, mpdf

I am creating a progress bar that looks like this as given below:
[Perfect Progress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jw3XB.png)

Now, I am using mPDF to add this progress bar to a PDF and the progress bar looks like this:

[Stretched Progress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzG7x.png)

I am assuming that this is related to css file. If yes can I add a simple code here to reset the width and height of the progress bar?

```
<?php
use setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi;

session_start();
ob_start();

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

require_once('FPDI/autoload.php');
require_once('fpdf/fpdf.php'); 
require_once('FPDI/Fpdi.php'); 

$pdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();

$pdf->AddPage(); 

$pdf->setSourceFile('file.pdf'); 

$tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1); 

$pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 0, 0, 297, 420, true); 

$html = '
<!-- default -->
<div class="clearfix">

    <div class="c100 p12 small">
        <span>12%</span>
        <div class="slice">
            <div class="bar"></div>
            <div class="fill"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

';

$stylesheet = file_get_contents('css/circle.css');
$pdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
$pdf->WriteHTML($html, 2);

$pdf->Output("NewFile.pdf", "D");
ob_end_flush(); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that.
In my experience with mPDF it is quite restrictive with its CSS, here is a list of the supported tags

https://mpdf.github.io/css-stylesheets/supported-css.html

Honestly, I wouldn't try to waste my time on it. mPDF makes it overly difficult to style anything using CSS

This method might be a little archaic but this is how I do it in mpdf if I don't want any issues.

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
   <tr>
     <td style="width:yourSetPixelValue">
        <img style='width: 100%' src='yourSvgOrImg'>
     </td>
     <td style="width:yourSetPixelValue">
        <div style='width: 100%'>some other content thats on the same row or x-axis</div>
     </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: So what could be an alternate way to achieve this? I just want to create a progress circular bar.

Comment: Does the progress bar need to be live updating? like you sign a portion and the progress increases? If not I would just use an SVG or image of some sort

Comment: No it does not need to be. I am not experienced with css and svgs. Could you please post an answer with css code?

Comment: I updated my answer. method maybe outdated but it works for me

Comment: Thanks but do you have a link for svg circle that is dynamic?